# How to list imported symbols in ELF executable?

Tags: linux, compile

For PE executable, I can list the imported symbols using

```
dumpbin /imports FILE.EXE
```

or using the depends utility which is GUI application.

`nm ELF-binary' just returns "no symbols".

Comment: see also [list the symbols in a .so file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732/how-do-i-list-the-symbols-in-a-so-file)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try this:

```sh
objdump -T 'ELF-file'
```

Comment: I thought objdump -T worked mainly on shared libraries...

Comment: well... not really, if I do: objdump -t /bin/ls it returns: "SYMBOL TABLE: no symbols", with -T (which lists DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE) outputs a lot of data, like: "00000000      DF *UND* 00000000  GLIBC_2.0   strchr"

Answer (score 9):

The output from objdump is a little excessive for this purpose, and requires a good bit of parsing to find the actual imports.

I prefer **readelf** for this purpose:

```
readelf -d dynamic-buffer-test

Dynamic section at offset 0x630a8 contains 23 entries:
 Tag                Type                 Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
```

As you can see, the required libraries are marked with "NEEDED".

Comment: It just depends on the mode in which you invoke it. Try `objdump -p /path/to/binary | grep NEEDED`.

Comment: This only seems to list libraries, not symbols.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer `readelf`.

`readelf -s <file>`

Comment: @Alcaro You have not tried this command. `-s` dumps the symbol table. In the table, you then have entries marked as undefined `UND` in the section index. These are the imported symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Along with the other answers posted here I would like to propose another. The contents printed are a function of the file format, where ELF lends itself nicely to solving this problem.

`objdump -p /path/to/binary | grep NEEDED`

The grep simply extracts the contents of the `Dynamic Section`, but its the format of the `objdump -p` output that makes this a simple solution.

Comment: This doesn't output imported symbols. Just library dependencies.